# Which program generates Hearthstone cards overview?

Tags: hearthstone

Which program generates the overview of the cards marked red in the following screen shot?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program Kripp is using is [Hearthstone Deck Tracker](https://hsdecktracker.net/).